# Query is working fine but is some case it not inserting data

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to PHP. I have developed one PHP page containing a simple form and it's working fine. All data are inserted correctly but sometimes the data is not inserted. Why this happens?

```
$sql="INSERT INTO form_tbl(name,age,dob) values('$name','$age','$dob')";
$exe=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if($exe){
  echo "success";
}else{
  echo "Submit again";
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Add echo mysqli_error($conn); in your else block to see the error

Comment: [How to get MySQLi error information in different environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments)

Comment: Show your complete code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get MySQLi error information in different environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to look for:

Make sure all your variables are not empty or else make sure your table is set up to allow NULL values.

```
if(isset($name) && $name!=""){
    //exists
}else{
    //doesn't exist or is empty
}
```

Make sure your variables are of the right type, ex., int, varchar, etc

Comment: yes i allow null values in tables but is that will create an problem.how?

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends what you are developing. For example you wouldn't allow NULL values if the fields were required. In this case if one of your values wasn't filled in and the table didn't allow a NULL value then it wouldn't insert anything.

Comment: To troubleshoot this further we'd need more information. Like where are you getting the variables from or how are you validating them (e.g. make sure it's an int or a string, etc,.) Add the following before what you have for troubleshooting: `echo $name;
echo $age;
echo $dob;
echo gettype($name);
echo gettype($age);
echo gettype($dob);`